# COUNT monthly sales for every year

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, count

I need to check monthly sales (count not sum) by area for long ranges of dates (5+ years), something like an Excel pivot table, currently I'm working it on Pandas but nobody here works with it so I'm trying to generate a view or a stored procedure in SQLServer for anyone who requires it. In this table sales are stored associated to an area and which product was.

I'm able to list and group AREA, SALES, MONTH AND YEAR, but as I mentioned, it would be easier to read if months or years where vertically aligned (there is about 100k records yearly and Excel lags at that point).

```
CREATE TABLE SALESHS
(
    IDAREA INT,
    DATEREG [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    IDPROD [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL
);
GO
-- Insert rows into table 'SALESHS'
INSERT INTO SALESHS
(
 IDAREA, DATEREG, IDPROD
)
VALUES
(
 1, '12/03/2019', 'xplpc'
),
(
 1, '15/03/2019', 'ndtlctm'
),
(
 2, '12/04/2019', 'wntd'
)
GO

SELECT IDAREA, 
    COUNT(IDAREA) AS CANT, 
    DATEREG, --DATE AS DD/MM/YYYY
    DATEPART(MM,CAST(DATEREG AS DATETIME)) AS MONTH, 
    DATEPART(YYYY,CAST(DATEREG AS DATETIME)) AS YEAR,
FROM saleshs
WHERE DATEREG > 201712
GROUP BY DATEREG , idarea
ORDER BY DATEREG
```

Which returns this:

```
IDAREA  AMOUNT  MONTH       YEAR    PER_PRO
----------------------------------------
1           2      03       2019    201904
2           1      04       2019    201904
```

Expected results:

```
IDAREA JAN2019 FEB2019 MAR2019 APR2019
--------------------------------------
1            0       0       2       0
2            0       0       0       1
```

I know the basics of SQL and I don't expect a full answer either, but anything that could help me build this view it's appreciated. I've tried PIVOT also but I can't count, distinct and sum in the same query.

Comment: What do you need COUNT, DISTINCT, and SUM for?

Comment: @influent COUNT sales, DISITINCT by area, SUM to pivot by month.

Comment: If you have SQL Reporting Services, you should be able to do this with a matrix in the report.

Comment: Are you stuck on MSSQL 2008?

Comment: @influent Yes. Still trying to pivot but can't add those aggregations.

Comment: Obviously, you need to use a dynamic pivot. I need some clarification. You have Jan and Feb in your expected result. But how about May, June, July...?

Comment: @influent This is just a "test table" to try any approach, the original has almost the same structure and it also has 100k rows with data from 2012 to this day.

Comment: @Rayén, please see my answer below and accept as answer if it works for what you desired for your result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Conditional Aggregation`

```
SELECT IDAREA, 
       SUM( CASE WHEN  YEAR(CAST(DATEREG AS DATETIME))= 2019 AND
                       MONTH(CAST(DATEREG AS DATETIME))=1 THEN
               1
            ELSE
               0
            END) JAN2019,
       SUM( CASE WHEN  YEAR(CAST(DATEREG AS DATETIME))= 2019 AND
                       MONTH(CAST(DATEREG AS DATETIME))=2 THEN
               1
            ELSE
               0
            END) FEB2019,
       SUM( CASE WHEN  YEAR(CAST(DATEREG AS DATETIME))= 2019 AND
                       MONTH(CAST(DATEREG AS DATETIME))=3 THEN
               1
            ELSE
               0
            END) MAR2019,
       SUM( CASE WHEN  YEAR(CAST(DATEREG AS DATETIME))= 2019 AND
                       MONTH(CAST(DATEREG AS DATETIME))=4 THEN
               1
            ELSE
               0
            END) APR2019            
 FROM saleshs
WHERE YEAR(CAST(DATEREG AS DATETIME))> 2017
GROUP BY IDAREA
ORDER BY IDAREA
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e74236807f50ea32f7aee0ac2d3d0ffc)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, I was trying this but I can't do 48 conditional aggregations for each month of the past 4 years. There is no easier way? :(

Comment: @Rayén you're welcome, I don't suppose whether exists such a method with a SQL statement, may be a cursor considered alternatively.

Answer (score 0):

```
--Build the column names for Pivot using dynamic SQL
DECLARE @YourChoice date
set @YourChoice = '2017/12/13' --change here to what date you want the earliest

declare @count int  = 0
declare @columnstr varchar(max)
declare @columnpivot varchar(max)
declare @onecolumnname varchar(20)

set @columnstr = ''
set @columnpivot = ''
set @onecolumnname = ''
while @count <= DATEDIFF(MONTH,@YourChoice,GETDATE())
begin
    set @onecolumnname = concat(cast(datename(month,dateadd(month,@count,@YourChoice)) as varchar(50)),cast(year(dateadd(month,@count,@YourChoice)) as varchar(10)))
    set @columnstr =  @columnstr + 'coalesce([' + @onecolumnname+ '],0) as '+@onecolumnname+', '
    set @columnpivot =  @columnpivot + '['+@onecolumnname+'], '
    set @count = @count + 1
end

set @columnstr = left(@columnstr,len(@columnstr)-1)
set @columnpivot = '('+left(@columnpivot,len(@columnpivot)-1)+')'

--Pivot time!
declare @str varchar(max)
set @str = 
'select IDAREA,' + @columnstr +' from (
select count(s.idarea) as amount,IDAREA,columnname from (
select *,datename(month,cast(substring(datereg,7,4)+''-''+substring(datereg,4,2)+''-''+substring(datereg,1,2) as datetime)) + SUBSTRING(datereg,7,4) as columnname
from SALESHS )s
group by IDAREA,columnname)s1
pivot
(
 max(s1.amount)
 for s1.columnname in '+@columnpivot+'
 ) p'
 exec (@str)
```

---

**Test Result 1 ('2017/12/13'):**

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=1b07fa457028c7dcd62a7b9149362b90)

**Test Result 2 ('2018/12/14'):**

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b0bbf4779d9f5379a0e5c6cd1ada2a20)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Dynamic SQL to solve this particular issue. Query can be adjusted on which `YEAR` to display in the result and which `Column` to count in the `PIVOT` Section of the query. Date format in the i have used is below query `MM/DD/YYYY`.

You can run the code <kbd>[HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7bd6a2d1705f40066d6265ffdb8ec779)</kbd>

Below is the SQL Query.

```
CREATE TABLE SALESHS
(   IDAREA INT,
    DATEREG date NOT NULL,
    IDPROD [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL
);
/* Insert rows into table 'SALESHS' */

INSERT INTO SALESHS
( IDAREA, DATEREG, IDPROD)
VALUES
( 1, '03/12/2019', 'xplpc'),
( 1, '03/15/2019', 'ndtlctm'),
( 2, '04/12/2019', 'wntd')

/* Create Calendar Table to capture all the dates for first day of month from start Date to end date */
CREATE TABLE Calendar
(
    [CalendarDate] DATE
    ,[MonthName] AS FORMAT(CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, CalendarDate), 0)), 'MMM-yyyy')
    ,[MonthNo] AS FORMAT(CalendarDate,'MM')  
    ,[Year] AS FORMAT(CalendarDate,'yyyy') 
    ,DateKey AS CONCAT(FORMAT(CalendarDate,'yyyy'), FORMAT(CalendarDate,'MM')) 
)

DECLARE @Date DATE, @StartDate DATE, @EndDate DATE
SET @Date = '01/01/2012'
SET @StartDate = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @Date), 0))  /* Set Start date to first day of the month for given date */
SET @EndDate = '04/01/2019'

WHILE @StartDate <= @EndDate
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Calendar (CalendarDate)
    SELECT @StartDate

    SET @StartDate = DATEADD(m, 1, @StartDate) 
END


/* Variable to hold unique Months to be used in PIVOT clause */
DECLARE @UniqueMonthsToPivot NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''
/* Extract unique Month names with pivot formattings */
SELECT @UniqueMonthsToPivot = @UniqueMonthsToPivot + ', [' + COALESCE(MonthName, '') + ']'
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MonthName FROM Calendar) DT
/* Remove first comma and space */
SELECT @UniqueMonthsToPivot = LTRIM(STUFF(@UniqueMonthsToPivot, 1, 1, ''))


/* Variable to hold pivot column names with alias to be used in SELECT Clause */
DECLARE @PivotMonthsToSelect NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''
/* Generate column names list for SELECT list with SUM Function and NULL handling. 
YEAR in the where condition can be adjust to select and show only certain year or month in Select list.
Order by CalendarDate is important to define the sequence of columns in the result  */
SELECT @PivotMonthsToSelect = @PivotMonthsToSelect + ', SUM(ISNULL([' + COALESCE(MonthName, '') + '], 0)) AS [' + MonthName + ']'
FROM Calendar WHERE Year >= 2012 
Order by CalendarDate

/* Variable to hold t-sql query */
DECLARE @SQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''
/* Generate dynamic PIVOT query here */
SET @SQLStatement =
N'SELECT IDAREA'
+ @PivotMonthsToSelect +  
'FROM (
        SELECT *
        ,CASE WHEN IDAREA IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IDAREA_Dup
        FROM Calendar C
        LEFT JOIN SALESHS S ON C.CalendarDate = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, DATEREG), 0))
      ) AA
PIVOT
     ( SUM(IDAREA_Dup)
            FOR MonthName IN ('+ @UniqueMonthsToPivot +')
     ) P
WHERE IDAREA IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY IDAREA
'
/* Check the generated dynamic t-sql PIVOT query below */
--PRINT (@SQLStatement)
/* Execute the generated dynamic t-sql PIVOT query below */
EXEC (@SQLStatement)
```